# Visualizing Database queries in different bars in Java with JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Alright, my goal is to visualize Database queries with JFreeChart.

It is easy for me to visualize one or more bars with just one query but I have no idea how to visualize two different queries in one 
visualization.

Please, look at my Code

```
public class Anfrage7 extends ConnectionTest {

    static DefaultCategoryDataset barChart = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    static int array[] = new int[2];

    public static int viewTable(Connection connection, String dbName) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet result = null;
        Statement statement;
        int anzahl = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            String sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS anzahl FROM " + dbName + " WHERE QUERY LIKE '%goodbye%letter%'";
            try {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                while (result.next()) {
                    anzahl = result.getInt("anzahl");
                    System.out.println("Anzahl:\t" + anzahl);
                    array[i - 1] = anzahl;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + e.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
        doBarChart(anzahl);
        return anzahl;
    }

    public static void doBarChart(int anzahl) throws SQLException {
        barChart.setValue(array[0], "Anfragemenge", "Goodbye Letter");
        barChart.setValue(array[1], "Anfragemenge", "Support Group");
        JFreeChart chartData = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("WURDE NACH SELBSTHILFEGRUPPEN / ABSCHIEDSBRIEF GESUCHT?",
                "SELBSTHILFEGRUPPE / ABSCHIEDSBRIEF", "ANFRAGEMENGE", barChart, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true,
                false);
        CategoryPlot categoryPlot = chartData.getCategoryPlot();
        BarRenderer br = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();
        br.setMaximumBarWidth(.15);
        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("/Users/dominic/Desktop/Anfrage7&10.jpeg"), chartData, 1200, 700);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }

}
```

So my first bar '%goodbye%letter%' is perfectly shown, but I need a second bar for '%support%group%' next to the first bar goodbye letter.

What do I need to do here? It's like I tried everything.
First I thought I just need to add a second String sql with a different query but it's no working.

Please keep in mind I am a total beginner and this query it topic in my class.

Comment: 1) *"Please, look at my Code"* Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB. 3) `} catch (Exception e) { System.err.println("Error" + e);` That is poor practice. Unless logging exceptions, it least print the stack trace. 4) *"Please keep in mind I am a total beginner"* Mixing DB ..

Comment: .. DB actions with 3rd party APIs is not for beginners. Start with simpler things.

Comment: Have a look at `JDBCCategoryDataset` and examine its source code.